# Jquery text replace for specific characters on entire site

Tags: jquery, replace

Basically what I need to do is replace question marks throughout the copy of an entire ecommerce site that has TONS of product descriptions.

The problem that I am getting is that quote marks are showing up as the diamond question marks on Apple. I was wondering if there was a simple jQuery .text() function I could do to search and destroy the "/' and insert the proper html code for the quotation marks.

Also, would this be really memory intense to do on page load?

Thanks for all your thoughts and recommendations!

Comment: Have a link to the site?

Answer (score 3):

I know @Matt Ball may disagree with this solution as it doesn't specifically address the real problem but just scoots it off to the side, but since the back-end php business was built by another group and I can't change their work this is a clean work around… visually.

```
var f = $("body"); 
f.html( f.html().replace(/"/g,"&rdquo;"));
```

Pretty simple really.
Just in case anyone was curious.

Thanks for trying everyone!